# CMake preload each test with a library

Tags: linux, cmake, ctest

In our Linux application we use a library that is preloaded with `LD_PRELOAD`.

I'd like to have the same library preloaded for each test. We are using CMake as build tool.

Can I tell CMake that it should add `LD_PRELOAD` to the environment for each test that is executed.

Test are executed with `make test`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_test.html) to register the individual tests, the most robust way to achieve this is to use [test properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-tests). The [`ENVIRONMENT` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_test/ENVIRONMENT.html) allows you to specify arbitrary environment variables that are being set for running the test:

```
add_test(NAME some_test COMMAND some_test_target)
add_test(NAME some_other_test COMMAND other_test_target)

set_property(TEST some_test some_other_test
   PROPERTY
   ENVIRONMENT LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/preload.so)
```

You also might want to escape the property with a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to keep the tests portable to platforms that do not support `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add that explicitely to all tests that were added with add_test so I don’t need to list them all explicitely in the set_property command.

Comment: @woodtluk Afaik, no. What some people like to do here is to add a wrapper function around `add_test` that does this automatically. Personally, I usually don't have a big issue with writing such things out explicitly. In the end, this is a highly opinion-based question, that depends largely on the specifics of your project, so you will have to decide yourself what is the best way to do this for your project.